# wordpress taxonomy query posts

Tags: categories, query-posts

I have categories and sub -categories with same name.. but I want to show only the  categories which is on the top level  and not in the sub categories

```
$qry=query_posts( array( 
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'custom_post',
    'author' => '12;,
    'showposts' => 9,
    'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'custom_cat,
        'terms' => 10,
        'field' => 'id'
    ) ),
    'orderby' => 'id',
    'order' => 'DESC'
));
```

my categories will be like

```
test
  --news
  --magzine
news
```

Answer (score 1):

See [Taxonomy Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) documentation - there is `include_children` parameter, which you can set to `false` in your taxonomy query.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
while($qry->have_posts()){
 $qry->the_post;
 foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {
   //check if category have parent or not
   if ($category->category_parent == 0) {
   //your code goes here for post
 }
}
```

**important Link**:

1. [get_the_category()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category)